Add spinner to right of checkbox on layout
I have the following layout:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/banner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/header"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:background="#000000" />
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:background="@color/colorGold"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/cancel"
                android:id="@+id/btnCancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp"
        android:background="#000000" />
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/selectParticipantsToRegister" />
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/listlayout">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/listlayout">
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

The code below adds a checkbox to the "listlayout" layout programmatically:
        for (int i=0; i < MyParticipants.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            feature1 = new CheckBox(this);
            feature1.Text = MyParticipants.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
            feature1.Id = Convert.ToInt32(MyParticipants.Tables[0].Rows[i]["employeeid"].ToString());
            feature1.CheckedChange += CheckBox_CheckedChange;
            list.AddView(feature1);
        }

This particular code is legacy and has been out in the wild for about 2 years now and runs fine.  I've been trying to add a spinner to the right of the checkbox and cannot seem to get it placed properly.  Any ideas?  My last attempt is:
        List<string> itemsNew = new List<string>();
        itemsNew.Add("Select Program");
        foreach (DataRow MyDataRow in MyProgramDataset.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            if (!MyDataRow["Program"].ToString().ToUpper().Contains("FLAG"))
            {
                itemsNew.Add(MyDataRow["Program"].ToString());
            }
        };
        for (int i=0; i < MyParticipants.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            feature1 = new CheckBox(this);
            feature1.Text = MyParticipants.Tables[0].Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
            feature1.Id = Convert.ToInt32(MyParticipants.Tables[0].Rows[i]["employeeid"].ToString());
            feature1.CheckedChange += CheckBox_CheckedChange;

            feature2 = new Spinner(this);
            // So I can identify which spinner belongs to which participant
            feature2.Id = Convert.ToInt32(MyParticipants.Tables[0].Rows[i]["employeeid"].ToString());
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.spinner_text_attr, itemsNew.ToArray());
            feature2.Adapter = adapter;
            list.AddView(feature1);
            // I need to place the spinner to the right of the checkbox
            list.AddView(feature2);
        }


"cannot seem to get it placed properly" - what does that mean?  What exactly is the problem with the code you have?

I need to place it on the same line as the check box, to the right.  Otherwise the code is correct.

A screenshot would be helpful
